# URLConnection sendSynchronousRequest Question?

Tags: ios, web-services

I am making a synchronous call to the web service and sometimes I get the correct result back from the web service and sometimes I get HTML result indicating a Runtime error. Is there anything on the iOS side I have to do to correctly call the web service. Here is my code:

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil; 
NSError *error = nil;         
NSString *requestString = @"some parameters!";        
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];        
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                     returningResponse:&response 
                                                 error:&error];    
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data 
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Is it because I am not releasing properly?

Comment: If it's a runtime error on the server and it's not being caused by a bad request from you, I don't think there's anything in the app you can do to fix it.

Comment: When you say you `get HTML result indicating a Runtime error`, is the app crashing or do you mean there is a server side error?  Like Flyingdiver said, there is nothing you can do if the failure is on the server's end.  Well, nothing you can do from the app I should say unless the error is caused by sending bad data.  i.e.  call webservice, addNumbers and pass it 'Z' and 'T' to add.  Server could return an error since inputs were invalid.

Comment: Thanks! The strange thing is that sometimes the web service returns the correct result and sometimes it returns runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the delegate methods of urlconnection like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
 [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 urLConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

and the following delegate methods do the trick

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  
{

    [receivedData appendData:data];

}
```

you will receive error in the following delegate if connection fails

```
  - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{}
```

you better get the response from the finished connection which tells that all the data been received

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  
{  
recievedData //the complete data 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    NSError * error;
NSURLResponse * urlresponse;

NSURL * posturl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"Type your webService URL here"];

NSMutableURLRequest * request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:posturl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:50];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSString * body=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fbid=%@",userid];
[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

NSData * data=[NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlresponse error:&error];

if (data==nil) {
    return;
}

id jsonResponse=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@" json response %@", jsonResponse);
if (![[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"code"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:200]]) {
    NSLog( @" successFull ");
```

this method works for me for more information read facebook  documents for ios login

Answer (score 0):

```
//set request    
NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://indianbloodbank.com/api/donors/?bloodgroup=O%2B"]];

NSLog(@"Request-%@",req);

NSError *err=nil;
NSURLResponse *res=nil;

NSData *xmldata=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&res error:&err];

NSLog(@"Error-%@",err);
NSLog(@"Response-%@",res);
NSLog(@"XmlData-%@",xmldata);

xmldictionary=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:xmldata error:&err];

NSLog(@"XmlDictionary-%@",xmldictionary);

mArray=[xmldictionary retrieveForPath:@"response.donorslist.donors"];

NSLog(@"MutableArray-%@",mArray);

lblname.text=[[mArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"name"];
lbllocation.text=[[mArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"location"];
lblphone.text=[[mArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"phone"];

NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@",lblname.text,lbllocation.text,lblphone.text);
NSLog(@"%@",mArray);
```

For loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<mArray.count; i++)
{
    Data * don=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Data" inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext];

    don.donorid=[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"id"];
    don.gender=[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"gender"];
    don.name=[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"];
    don.location=[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"location"];
    don.phone=[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"phone"];

    [app saveContext];

    NSLog(@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"id"],[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"gender"],[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"name"],[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"location"],[[mArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"phone"]);

}
```

Comment: Hi Arun. Add some details about what should be changed exactly. Write some descriptive text also.